# Get CustomLayoutPtr from CustomLayoutsPtr in PowerPoint API

Tags: c++, vba, visual-studio, powerpoint

I am trying to load a pot file and use its layouts depending on the requirements.

In VBA it is something like this:

```
    Sub setLayout()
    Call LoadDesign

    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(3)

    End Sub

    Sub LoadDesign()
        ActivePresentation.Designs.Load TemplateName:="C:\myPptTemplate.pot", Index:=1
    End Sub
```

In C++, I tried:

```
    PowerPoint::DesignPtr my_design= my_active_presentation->Designs->Load(as_bstr(template_filename), 1);
    PowerPoint::CustomLayoutsPtr my_layouts = my_design->SlideMaster->CustomLayouts;
    PowerPoint::CustomLayoutPtr my_layout = my_layouts->Item(_variant_t(1));
```

It is working fine in VBA, but not in C++.
I cannot get a CustomLayoutPtr from my_layouts. It throws an exception E_INVALIDARG.

I would be thankful if you share any ideas about how can I fix this issue.

Ref:

MSO API 2007

VS2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use:

```
    long i=1;
    _variant_t index(i, VT_I4);
```

VT_I4  4-byte signed integer.

On a 32-bit system, VT_INT is a 32-bit signed integer.

On a 64-bit system, VT_INT is a 64-bit signed integer.

I am having a 64-bits, but still VT_INT didn't work. Maybe some internal issues.

Hope it will help.